# How to return data api(fractal) from field table has set default value?

Tags: php, database, laravel, api

I want return data for default avatar from field table, I set value of field as **default.png**, when I return data is show null, what I can do ?

```
public function register(Request $request, User $user){
    $this->validate($request, [
        'fullname'  => 'required',
        'company'   => 'required',
        'email'     => 'required|email|unique:users',
        'password'  => 'required|min:8',
        'referall'  => 'required'
    ]);

    $user = $user->create([
        'fullname'  => $request->fullname,
        'company'   => $request->company,
        'email'     => $request->email,
        'password'  => bcrypt($request->password),
        'api_token' => bcrypt($request->email),
        'id_role'   => 2,
        'referall'  => $request->referall
    ]);

    $response = fractal()
        ->item($user)
        ->transformWith(new UserTransformer)
        ->addMeta([
            'token' => $user->api_token,
            'avatar' => $user->avatar,
        ])
        ->toArray();

    return response()->json($response, 201);
}
```

[Field table for avatar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xgz1N.png)
[Return API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DxJDR.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *are* passing a value (albeit `NULL`, which is a valid value) to the row so it will show as `NULL`. Change it to:

```
$response = fractal()
    ->item($user)
    ->transformWith(new UserTransformer)
    ->addMeta([
        'token' => $user->api_token,
        'avatar' => $user->avatar ?? 'default.png',
    ])
    ->toArray();
```

Default values are only used if the value is omitted, not when `NULL` is passed as value.

**Reading Material**

[Null coalescing operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op)